# Single row UICollectionView dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I am working with a `UICollectionView` that is only supposed to show 1 row of horizontally scrollable content.

It contains cells of multiple heights. I am trying to achieve a behaviour where the `UICollectionView` adjusts it's own height depending on the maximum height of its cells.

For example (assuming no padding/insets for `UICollectionView`'s content)

- If all the cells' height is 20, height of UICollectionView should be 20.
- But if there is at least 1 cell with height 40, then UICollectionView's height also becomes 40.

I am using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and returning size (height) for each cell using `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Is there only one cell in each row?  Something like a tablet view

Comment: try to use `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting`

Comment: @MohammadRazipour 1 UICollectionView in each UITableViewCell. But there can be multiple UICollectionViewCells in UICollectionView

Comment: @a.masri do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use automatic size of an item, assuming that constraints for the `UICollectionViewCell` you are using are well created/implemented. Then, you can add this and it should work

```
var collectionLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout! {
  didSet {
    collectionLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
  }
}
```

Comment: but how would UICollectionView change it's height so that there is no extra padding or it doesn't crop UICollectionViewCell in it?